# focus bar chart using d3

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I try to modify [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) and get a bar chart with focus via brushing. Here is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Fvtz9/)

Problems are:

1. bars on mini-graph doesn't reflect behaviour of bars on the main graph (their height, width, position)
2. the maximum value on mini `x-axis`, when I use brushing, is 900, not 600150
3. brush scope (when I use it) oversteps the limits and covers the `main-chart-space`
4. when I try to focus on, for instance, two bars - it works, but I always see only one bar and it's drived into `y-axis`.

Comment: Could you place your working code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so someone can have a look and help you.

Comment: anyway,it doesn`t help